# How do I inject a userscript into a site that uses CSP?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, content-security-policy

I'm currently in the process of writing a userscript for a certain website. What I'm trying to accomplish requires access to the content scope with the page variables and functions.

Standard operating procedure for that sort of thing seems to be a function that injects a new `<script>` tag into the DOM, like so:

```js
function injectScript(f) {
    var target = document.head || document.documentElement;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.text = "(" + f.toString() + ")();";

    target.appendChild(script);
    target.removeChild(script);
}
```

However, this approach doesn't work because the website has a Content Security Policy which prevents the injected script tag from executing! I've also tried the location hack (basically `location.href="javascript:someCode()"`), but that *also* counts as an inline script and won't work.

`unsafeWindow` would be an option that is unfortunately only available with Greasemonkey. Ideally my script should work with Chrome as well. Is there a better way to access page variables?

Comment: `unsafeWindow` also works in Chrome if you install and use Tampermonkey -- which you should anyway; it's much better for most tasks than vanilla Chrome userscript.

Comment: Looks like a GM and TM feature request, or code fork, might be needed.  Meanwhile check out [UserCSP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/newusercspdesign/) for Firefox.  There are probably similar extensions for Chrome.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thank you, didn't know about Tampermonkey. I guess that'll do if there's no good solution for vanilla Chrome.

Comment: The **[`GM_addElement()`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_addElement)** API should make this possible in Tampermonkey. See the documentation examples for more details.